# IEnumerable file comparison

Tags: c#, csv

I'm trying to modify the following method so it will show the column names of the non matched items in the in the output of the 2 CSV file I'm comparing:

```
public static void CompareCSVFiles_2(string file1, string file2)
{
    string[] names1 = File.ReadAllLines(file1);
    string[] names2 = File.ReadAllLines(file2);

    IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery =  names1.Except(names2);

    foreach (string s in differenceQuery)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The format of the 2 files I'm trying to compare is plain CSV for example:

```
CSV_1                          CSV_2    

Column_1  Column_2 Column_3    Column_1  Column_2 Column_3 
123       hhh      bbb         123       hhh      bbb
135       ddd      lll         135       ddd      zzz
```

The output I'm after needs to indicate not only that a diff was found between the 2 files but also indicate the column name. 
For example:
'Diff found in Column_3, line 2'.

I do know that the 'Column' is just line [0] in the CSV but what am I'm missing here ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation compares the two files row by row. If you want to find the differences in columns, you have to parse the rows first.

There is a good nuget package called [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) that helps you with the parsing. Check the "Reading" > "Reading by Hand example" on their website to see how to read the file column by column.